# Fake location on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, geolocation

i want to change the location on my browser, i navigate to

`about:config`

I set

`geo.enabled` to true

Then on

`geo.wifi.uri`

I put

`data:application/json,{"location":{"latitude":xxx,"longitude":yyy,"accuracy":10}}`

I restart the browser after those changes, i am using firefox 54, but when i verify it, its telling me my real location, why it is not working? what i am doing wrong?

Comment: if your method not working, you can use Location Guard extension

Comment: Thank you, but i want to do it manually

Answer (score 6):

I am using Firefox 74.0 with Selenium/Python 3.141.0 and the following places me in NYC. This works manually or with selenium.

```
geo.prompt.testing, True
geo.prompt.testing.allow, True
geo.provider.testing, True
geo.provider.network.url, "data:application/json,{"location": {"lat": 40.7590, "lng": -73.9845}, "accuracy": 27000.0}"
```