# How can I fake my location in Firefox using R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, location

I want to **scrape** the US apps of Play Store, but I am in Brazil.
How can I fake my location using R? I am using Firefox.

This is my code:

```
urls <- c('https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=0g4jCiEKG3RvcHNlbGxpbmdfZnJlZV9BUFBMSUNBVElPThAHGAM%3D:S:ANO1ljKs-KA&gsr=CibSDiMKIQobdG9wc2VsbGluZ19mcmVlX0FQUExJQ0FUSU9OEAcYAw%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljL40zU',
          'https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=0g4jCiEKG3RvcHNlbGxpbmdfcGFpZF9BUFBMSUNBVElPThAHGAM%3D:S:ANO1ljLdnoU&gsr=CibSDiMKIQobdG9wc2VsbGluZ19wYWlkX0FQUExJQ0FUSU9OEAcYAw%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljIKVpg',
          'https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=0g4fCh0KF3RvcGdyb3NzaW5nX0FQUExJQ0FUSU9OEAcYAw%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljLe6QA&gsr=CiLSDh8KHQoXdG9wZ3Jvc3NpbmdfQVBQTElDQVRJT04QBxgD:S:ANO1ljKx5Ik',
          'https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=0g4cChoKFHRvcHNlbGxpbmdfZnJlZV9HQU1FEAcYAw%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljJ_Y5U&gsr=Ch_SDhwKGgoUdG9wc2VsbGluZ19mcmVlX0dBTUUQBxgD:S:ANO1ljL4b8c',
          'https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=0g4cChoKFHRvcHNlbGxpbmdfcGFpZF9HQU1FEAcYAw%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljLtt38&gsr=Ch_SDhwKGgoUdG9wc2VsbGluZ19wYWlkX0dBTUUQBxgD:S:ANO1ljJCqyI',
          'https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=0g4YChYKEHRvcGdyb3NzaW5nX0dBTUUQBxgD:S:ANO1ljLhYwQ&gsr=ChvSDhgKFgoQdG9wZ3Jvc3NpbmdfR0FNRRAHGAM%3D:S:ANO1ljIKta8')

flw_rk <- vector("list", length(urls))
df_total_rk = data.frame()
selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.firefox.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()

for (i in urls){ 
  
  remDr$navigate(i)
  for(j in 1:5){      
    remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",j*10000,");"))
    Sys.sleep(3)    
  }
    
  html_obj <- remDr$getPageSource(header = TRUE)[[1]] %>% read_html()
  
  names <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".WsMG1c.nnK0zc") %>% html_text()
  
  flw_rk[[i]] <- data.frame(names = names, stringsAsFactors = F)
}
```

Comment: Your location is determined by your IP address. There’s nothin you can do in R to change your IP address. You’ll have to use something like a VPN to route your request through a different server.

Comment: But it seems that it is possible to do it using Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60025987/fake-location-on-firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a Virtual Private Network(VPN). No need for over-complicated solutions. I found one that is free and works best for me. Here's the link to the Google Play Store App:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=free.vpn.unblock.proxy.turbovpn

Also, You could try to download a VPN extension from the Mozilla Add-on store. Here's the link: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/setupvpn/

**EDIT**
**This** add-on will work for an **unlimited amount of time**. This is what I think **will be the best choice** for you now.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/touch-vpn/?src=search

Comment: The free version only works for a short period of time. The add-on did not work when I ran the code.

Comment: Found It!!!! Check the updated answer :) This one will work for unlimited amount of time and there is no need for registration. It just plugs and plays that's how simple it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add **gl=us** at the end of the URL:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=0g4YChYKEHRvcGdyb3NzaW5nX0dBTUUQBxgD:S:ANO1ljLhYwQ&gsr=ChvSDhgKFgoQdG9wZ3Jvc3NpbmdfR0FNRRAHGAM%3D:S:ANO1ljIKta8&gl=us
```

This is how we solved the location issue when scraping the Play Store at [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/google-play-api).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux you can spoof your location by using a proxy,
to use a proxy in linux(debian/ubuntu) do the following steps:

1.type `sudo apt-get install proxychains`

2.type `proxychains <path to code>`

Please note these steps are specific to debain and ubuntu but can be done using other operating linux sysytem's if you use the operating sytems package manager.

If you are using windows try using tor-browser which is based on firefox.Tor browser automatically sets up multiple proxys for you.However Tor is better for better for browsing and not technical(code) solutions

Another more flexible windows alternative for more technical(code) solutions is [proxifier](http://proxifier.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I am using windows. How can I use rselenium to scrap a website with tor?

Comment: Rather use proxifier for web scraping